# Execute user's code using CodeAnalysis CSharpScript (.NET Core)

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn

I'm trying to execute simple user's formula.

I'm using MS VS 2017 15.2 (26430.16), .NET Core 1.1.

I followed:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples

I created ASP.NET Core Web App, added NuGet package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting
```

But after that the app gave an error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentException: Must include private members unless emitting a ref assembly.
Parameter name: IncludePrivateMembers
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.Emit(Stream peStream, Stream pdbStream, Stream xmlDocumentationStream, Stream win32Resources, IEnumerable<ResourceDescription> manifestResources, EmitOptions options, IMethodSymbol debugEntryPoint, Stream sourceLinkStream, IEnumerable<EmbeddedText> embeddedTexts, Stream metadataPEStream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

After I added

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
```

for

```
object result = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("1 + 2");
```

but it wasn't seen, so I added

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting" Version="2.3.1" />
```

in "MyProject.csproj".

But I have the same error.

Can somebody help me?

**Update 1:**

Stack:

```
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.Emit(Stream peStream, Stream pdbStream, Stream xmlDocumentationStream, Stream win32Resources, IEnumerable<ResourceDescription> manifestResources, EmitOptions options, IMethodSymbol debugEntryPoint, Stream sourceLinkStream, IEnumerable<EmbeddedText> embeddedTexts, Stream metadataPEStream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRoslynCompilationService.Compile(RelativeFileInfo fileInfo, string compilationContent)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorCompilationService.Compile(RelativeFileInfo file)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.CompilerCache.CreateCacheEntry(string relativePath, string normalizedPath, Func<RelativeFileInfo, CompilationResult> compile)
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.CompilerCache.GetOrAdd(string relativePath, Func<RelativeFileInfo, CompilationResult> compile)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider.CreateFactory(string relativePath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.CreateCacheResult(HashSet<IChangeToken> expirationTokens, string relativePath, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.OnCacheMiss(ViewLocationExpanderContext expanderContext, ViewLocationCacheKey cacheKey)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromViewLocations(ActionContext actionContext, string pageName, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, string viewName, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.CompositeViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, string viewName, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor.FindView(ActionContext actionContext, ViewResult viewResult)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult+<ExecuteResultAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeResultAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.BrowserLinkMiddleware+<ExecuteWithFilter>d__7.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

**Update 2:**

Finally I did it this way (without packages):

```
string user_code = "1 + 2";
string code = $"int? r = {user_code};";
string codeToCompile = @"using System;
namespace RoslynCompile
{
    public class Calculator
    {
        public int? Calculate()
        {
            " + code + @"
            return r;
        }
    }
}";
SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(codeToCompile);
string assemblyName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
MetadataReference[] references = new MetadataReference[]
{
MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location)
};
CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
    assemblyName,
    syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree },
    references: references,
    options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    EmitResult emitResult = compilation.Emit(ms);
    if (!emitResult.Success)
    {
        // some errors
        IEnumerable<Diagnostic> failures = emitResult.Diagnostics.Where(diagnostic =>
            diagnostic.IsWarningAsError ||
            diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        Assembly assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(ms);
        var type = assembly.GetType("RoslynCompile.Calculator");
        var instance = assembly.CreateInstance("RoslynCompile.Calculator");
        var meth = type.GetMember("Calculate").First() as MethodInfo;
        // get result
        int? result = meth.Invoke(instance, null) as int?;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what causes this error, but we rolled back to `v2.2.0` of the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` package.

It seems to have started happening since `v2.3.0`. At the time of writing, `v2.3.1` is out, and still causes this problem.

Check out the [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/20873) on GitHub.